# Can not receive response from server?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a code as below :

```
 public static void sendData()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var URI = new Uri("abc.com");
            string str = "data=1234";
            wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc__UploadStringCompleted);
            wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", str);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string temp = ex.Message;
        }
    }

   public static void wc__UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string tt = e.Result;
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }

    }
```

It was send sucessfull to server but it can not reciced data response.Please show me how to response data,i want get response at sendData method not delegate and wc__UploadStringCompleted is not call

Comment: If you do not need support for WP7, I would use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. Much more friendly when used with `async-await` pattern. The package is available through `NuGet` and takes a second to install and a minute to get used to. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.18

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async Task<string> sendData()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> complete = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    try
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var URI = new Uri("abc.com");
        string str = "data=1234";
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string tt = e.Result;
                complete.SetResult(tttt);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                complete.SetException(exc);
            }
        }
        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", str);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string temp = ex.Message;
        complete.SetException(ex);
    }

    return await complete.Task;
}
```

Usage:

```
public async void foo()
{
    string response = await sendData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant, you want the response inside the `sendData()` method you could hook up the handler in `sendData()` itself..

```
wc.UploadStringCompleted += (s,e)=>
{
    try
    {
        string tt = e.Result;
    }

    catch (Exception exc)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Using an inline delegate is still handing over control to another function, technically.

Comment: yep sure.. my guess being he needs some variable from sendData() accessible in the completed handler..

Comment: That is what `UserState` is for. No need to keep the delegate inline in order to share data.

Comment: Other ways violate encapsulation, IMHO :)

Comment: Not sure I understand.. :/ can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure. In this way, you technically define a function inside another function. And you use variables defined in one function, inside another without passing them in and in doing this you circumvent variable scope (in the classical sense).